# Simplified algorithm for calculating remaining space in a circular buffer?

Tags: c++, circular-buffer

I was wonder if there is a simpler (single) way to calculate the remaining space in a circular buffer than this?

```
int remaining = (end > start)
                ? end-start
                : bufferSize - start + end;
```

Comment: That looks good to me.  The only other option is if this is in a class then maintaining the remaining space in a variable.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you're worried about poorly-predicted conditionals slowing down your CPU's pipeline, you could use this:

```
int remaining = (end - start) + (-((int) (end <= start)) & bufferSize);
```

But that's likely to be premature optimisation (unless you have really identified this as a hotspot).  Stick with your current technique, which is much more readable.

Answer (score 6):

Hmmm....

```
int remaining = (end - start + bufferSize) % bufferSize;
```

13 tokens, do I win?

Comment: That is brief, although adding a divide will make your version slower on most architectures.

Comment: So make the buffer size a power of 2.

Comment: 12 years and no one mentioned this calc is `size` not `remaining` :) +2 tokens to fix

Answer (score 5):

If your circular buffer size is a power of two, you can do even better by having `start` and `end` represent positions in a virtual stream instead of indices into the circular buffer's storage. Assuming that `start` and `end` are unsigned, the above becomes:

```
int remaining= bufferSize - (end - start);
```

Actually getting elements out of the buffer is a little more complicated, but the overhead is usually small enough with a power of 2 sized circular buffer (just masking with `bufferSize - 1`) to make all the other logic of your circular buffer much simpler and cleaner. Plus, you get to use all the elements since you no longer worry about `end==start`!

Answer (score 2):

According to the C++ Standard, section 5.6, paragraph 4:

> The binary / operator yields the quotient, and the binary % operator yields the remainder from the division of the first expression by the second.  If the second operand of / or % is zero the behavior is undefined; otherwise (a/b)*b + a%b is equal to a.  If both operands are nonnegative then the remainder is nonnegative; if not, the sign of the remainder is implementation-defined.

A footnote suggests that rounding the quotient towards zero is preferred, which would leave the remainder negative.

Therefore, the `(end - start) % bufferSize` approaches do not work reliably.  C++ does not have modular arithmetic (except in the sense offered by unsigned integral types).

The approach recommended by j_random_hacker is different, and looks good, but I don't know that it's any actual improvement in simplicity or speed.  The conversion of a boolean to an int is ingenious, but requires mental parsing, and that fiddling could be more expensive than the use of ?:, depending on compiler and machine.

I think you've got the simplest and best version right there, and I wouldn't change it.

Comment: Agreed -- code clarity beats a 0.001% speed increase any day!  :)

Answer (score 0):

Lose the conditional:

```
int remaining = (end + bufferSize - start - 1) % bufferSize + 1
```

Edit:  The `-1` and `+1` are for the case when `end == start`.  In that case, this method will assume the buffer is empty.  Depending on the specific implementation of your buffer, you may need to adjust these to avoid an off-by-1 situation.

Comment: In C and C++, the % isn't a real modulo operator, but rather a remainder.  The difference is that, when one of the operands is negative, the sign of the result is implementation-defined.

Comment: Doesn't buffersize + 1 need to be between parentheses?

Comment: and adding an abs() call would slow it down, too

Answer (score 0):

Older thread I know but thought this might be helpful.

Not sure how fast this implements in C++ but in rtl we do this if size is n^2

```
remaining = (end[n] ^ start[n])
            ? start[n-1:0] - end[n-1:0]
            : end[n-1:0] - start[n-1:0];
```

or

```
remaining = if (end[n] ^ start[n]) {
              start[n-1:0] - end[n-1:0]
            } else { 
              end[n-1:0] - start[n-1:0] 
            };
```