# Virtual stream for Circular Queue

Tags: queue, circular-buffer

I would like to implement a circular queue which grows and shrinks in size() dynamically for my application. When searching stack overflow for related threads, I came across this
[Simplified algorithm for calculating remaining space in a circular buffer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/450558/simplified-algorithm-for-calculating-remaining-space-in-a-circular-buffer) where MSN has mentioned about virtual streams.

Have anyone used this kind of indexing for circular queues ? Some background on this would help me implement this mechanism.

Answer (score 1):

well you know the size of the queue, and if you use a counter of occupied cells while you are visiting them, you can find the number of cells that are free easily.

however, if your queue will grow when the size is over the load factor, and keep expanding, which you wont know when to shrink. then why not use just queue.

personally i always find circular queues useful when are fixed in size. otherwise a queue would do the same.